# How to get time at midnight of an user from my server?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I have an user with the timezone (for example: +7 GMT).

In PHP language:

1. My server is set timezone at 0-GMT.
2. How could I know from my server that now is midnight of that user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the timezine of the user saved (I'll use `America/Los_Angeles` since that is currently GMT -7 right now)

```
$user_tz = 'America/Los_Angeles'; // get from your db
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($user_tz))
if ($dt->format('g') == 0 && $dt->format('i') == '00')
{
    echo "it's midnight";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't with PHP since it isn't running on the users computer, another option wold be using the getTimezoneOffset() in javascript.

Comment: If I get current hour at my server is 17, I can say that: It is the midnight of that user?